# Grid engine cluster + OpenCV: strange behaviour

Tags: c++, opencv, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I'm using a Grid Engine cluster for running some OpenCV code. The code runs well when executed locally, but when submitted to the grid it's not working. I extracted here a minimal example.

In the directory `~/code/` I have a file `test.cpp` containing the following code:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main(int ac, char** av)
{    
    /// Create a random matrix
    Mat M;

    /// Create a subfolder
    string folderName = "sub/";
    mkdir(folderName.c_str(),0777);

    return 0;
}
```

The code is compiled without errors.

When executing locally, i.e.

```
username@machine:~/code$ ./test
```

it creates a subfolder, i.e. `~/code/sub`, as expected.

For submitting to the grid, I created a job script `job.sh` in the home directory (i.e. `~/job.sh`) containing

```
cd code/
./test
```

and then submit using

```
qsub job.sh
```

Nothing happened. (And no errors).

**However, when I removed the line**

```
Mat M;
```

**it did create the folder as expected.**

What are the possible reasons for this behaviour? I'm thinking of something like the shared libs of OpenCV weren't installed in other computers of the grid, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to verify that.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: To help diagnose further you a can put a print statement before and after the `Mat M` statement. I suspect you are correct that the lib is missing on the execution nodes. Do you have interactive ssh access to these nodes?

Comment: @Vince: Yes I have access to those nodes. Do I have to install the libraries to all of these nodes? Maybe I have just to modify the sge_conf file and change the SET_LIB_PATH variable? (http://linux.die.net/man/5/sge_conf)

Comment: The libraries need to be accessible to all execution nodes in queue you want to submit job to. If execution nodes have access to shared location, such as NFS mount, you can install the libraries there. Otherwise, you need to install required libs on all execution nodes.  Additional link regarding SET_LIB_PATH: https://blogs.oracle.com/templedf/entry/inheriting_job_environment.  While this would help point to right location, the libraries still need to be accessible.

Comment: @Vince: please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libraries need to be accessible to all execution nodes in queue you want to submit job to. If execution nodes have access to shared location, such as NFS mount, you can install the libraries there. Otherwise, you need to install required libs on all execution nodes. Additional link regarding SET_LIB_PATH:

[blogs.oracle.com/templedf/entry/inheriting_job_environment](http://blogs.oracle.com/templedf/entry/inheriting_job_environment)

While this would help point to right location, the libraries still need to be accessible