# Grid engine and shared libraries

Tags: cluster-computing, sungridengine

My question is: If I have an executable that requires some libs, then do I have to install these libs to all the nodes of the grid, or is there a way to install the libs on one node and then share to all the others?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this related to post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308416/grid-engine-cluster-opencv-strange-behaviour ? If so, please consider removing one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your nodes run the same system (same architecture, version etc.), you should be able to store the libs on a shared drive. Note that reading the libs frequently from a shared location might impact speed of the executables.

Comment: Hi choroba. Thanks for the answer. How do I know if there is a shared drive and how to locate it?

Comment: @Nesbit: Ask your cluster admin? Or do some experiments: run `mount` on the cluster and examine the result...